# CKEditor in Rails 5, don't show toolbar

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, ckeditor, toolbar

Add CKEdito to Rails proj. it worked but toolbar isn't displayed.

Gemfile.

[image]

_form.html.erb

```
<div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :body%>
    <%= f.cktext_area :body, class: 'form-control'%>
</div>
```

assets.rb

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w[ckeditor/config.js]
```

post_controller.eb

> ```
> class PostsController < ApplicationController   before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update,:destroy]
> ```
>
> def index       @posts = Post.all   end
>
> def create
>       @post = Post.new(post_params)
>       if @post.save
>         redirect_to @post, success: "Saved!"
>       else 
>         flash[:danger] = "Not Saved!"
>         render :new
>       end   end
>
> def show
>        end
>
> def edit
>          end
>
> ```
>  def new
>    @post = Post.new   end
> ```
>
> def update
>
> ```
> if @post.update_attributes(post_params)
>   redirect_to @post, success: "Saved!"
> else 
>   flash[:danger] = "Not Saved!"
>   render :edit
> end   end
> ```
>
> def destroy
>
> ```
> @post.destroy
>
> redirect_to posts_path, success: "Deleted!"   end
> ```
>
> private
>
> ```
> def post_params
>   params.require(:post).permit(:title, :summary, :body, :image) #image add by gem magick
> end
> def set_post
>   @post = Post.find(params[:id])
> end end
> ```

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

In your application `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` add the below line.This is call to the JS initializer. it will load the ckeditor tools for your app.

```
//= require ckeditor/init
```

Comment: Error...on ckeditor github page no word about this line of code

Sprockets::FileNotFound in Posts#new
couldn't find file 'ckeditor/init' with type 'application/javascript'

Comment: For my application it is working. in which file you added 'require ckeditor/init'

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code such that others can learn from it - what does that line do?

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: @RajkumarUlaganadhan which Rails version you use?

Comment: @Axelrod i am using Rails 5.1.4